# Formatting a CSV file, split a column into rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `CSV` file, of the following type:

[image]

I need to reformat it to the following form:

[image]

Could you tell me please, how can column `Column_B` be divided into rows, but only so that column `Column_A` is filled with corresponding values according to column `Column_B`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you could read csv roms using csv module and split second column using `str.split`, write csv back. did you attempt something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend leveraging [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) after modifying `Column_B` to a `list`-type:

```
df = pd.read_csv(text, sep=';')

df['Column_B'] = df['Column_B'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('Column_B')

df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to retrieve your CSV file content into raw text.

```py
content = "..."
final_content = ""

# a readable solution
for line in content.split('\n'):
    key = line.split(';')[0]
    vals = line.split(';')[1].split(',')
    final_content += key+";"+vals[0]+"\n"
    final_content += key+";"+vals[1]+"\n"
```

The same solution, but looks shorter

```py
final_content = "\n".join([line.split(';')[0]+":"line.split(';')[1].split(",")[0]+'\n'+line.split(';')[0]+":"line.split(';')[1].split(",")[1] for line in content.split('\n')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to split lines and create those two lines out of a single line. Here is a step by step solution: (I explained it with my variable names)

```py
with open('old.csv') as f:
    # storing the header
    header = next(f)

    res = []
    for line in f:
        with_semicolon_part, without_semicolumn_part = line.rstrip().split(',')
        first_part, second_part = with_semicolon_part.split(';')
        lst = [first_part, second_part, without_semicolumn_part]

        res.append(lst)

# creating new csv file with our `res`.
with open('new.csv', mode='w') as f:
    f.write(header)
    for lst in res:
        f.write(lst[0] + ';' + lst[1] + '\n')
        f.write(lst[0] + ';' + lst[2] + '\n')
```